# Get the signed bit of a float

Tags: c

I'm trying to find a way to check if a floating point number is negative without branching.

```
float a = -0.5;
int getSignOfa= *(int*)&a >> 31; //type-pun to int and get signed bit;
```

Is this a safe way of checking the signed bit of a float?

Comment: safe? no, since there's no guarantee that `float` is the same size as `int`, and that also violates the strict aliasing rule

Comment: Please pick one programming language. You've tagged 2. Solutions differ.

Comment: @phuclv assuming both float and int are 32 bit and the strict aliasing rule is disabled, will it work 100%?

Comment: Be aware this kind of type casting can be extremely slow depending upon the target architecture.  On powerpc this will take the floating point value in the register.  Save it to memory on the stack. Read it back from memory to put it into a GPR register. Then shift and mask the GPR register.  Or you could have had a single `int negative = a < 0.0f` which is two instructions.

Comment: No, it won't always work.  Depending upon compiler and optimization levels the compiler can see that this operation in undefined by the C language and set getSignOfa to anything it wants.  See http://blog.qt.io/blog/2011/06/10/type-punning-and-strict-aliasing/

Comment: @Zachwuzhere Most of what you are writing is implementation defined. That's the point of writing in a language other than assembly. The compiler will do what it thinks is best for your processor architecture. Use something in the language like `signbit` if you want the best performance for this because even inline assembly can cause the complier to do extra register rearranging to accommodate it.

Comment: Whats wrong with what eg. clang -O3 produces for `!(v < 0.f)` *~>* `xorps xmm1, xmm1 \ 
 ucomiss xmm1, xmm0 \ setbe al` ? (gcc -03 *~>* `pxor xmm1, xmm1 \ comiss  xmm1, xmm0 \ setbe al`)

Comment: @Swordfish Nothing, it's the best way of checking if it is negative.  I tried pointing out that comparisons don't branch (that's what if statements and functions call do) but maybe didn't word it very well.

Comment: Does `NaN` need to be handled? If you know that won't happen by the time this code is reached, a comparison makes much more sense than checking the sign bit. If `NaN` does need to be handled, you're probably going to have to branch to take care of it anyway. At that point, you're back at the first case where the comparison makes much more sense again.

Comment: @Fred *best way of checking if it is negative.* – Ah, the op wanted negative ... well, add another bang ^^

Comment: @Swordfish Not necessary `<` already returns zero or one.  But `!!` is great for normalizing numbers to zero or one.

Comment: @Free seems you didn't notice the ***^^***

Comment: there are a lot of related and duplicate questions: [How to get the sign, mantissa and exponent of a floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15685181/995714), [How can I access the sign bit of a number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001653/995714), [Sign of a floating point number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4235235/995714), [How can I access the sign bit of a number in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3001653/995714)...

Comment: @Fred [example on how it's done on various architectures](https://godbolt.org/z/WVqaWg). I don't know about powerpc but it looks like the compiler indeed stores to memory and reload instead of moving from FPR to GPR like on many other architectures

Comment: @phuclv Please change /O3 to /O2 for msvc and see \* *magic* \* ;)

Answer (score 6):

Since C99, you can use `signbit(x)` as defined in `math.h` to get the sign bit of a floating point number. It returns 0 if `x` is positive (sign bit not set) and nonzero if negative (sign bit is set).

Comment: Is the signbit function brachless?

Comment: It's required to be implemented as a macro, but it is otherwise implementation-defined.

Comment: [it's not a macro in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit). @Zachwuzhere why you you care about that? Benchmark and if it's really slow then optimize it, otherwise it's premature optimization. The way from the standard is often the better solution

Comment: I'm just going to add that `bool s = a < 0.0f` doesn't branch.  It's a comparison that is probably just some sort of fsub instruction and then masks and shifts the floating point status register.  Also what about NAN and Infinity?

Comment: I'm creating a branchess ray-triangle intersection method for ray tracing and need it to be as fast as possible because there are millions of tests per second.

Comment: @Fred that too is implementation-defined.

Comment: @Zachwuzhere that's better leave to the GPU, not CPU

Answer (score 0):

You may use `copysign()` functions available in `math.h` to get the sign of `float` number.

```
float sign = copysign(1, float_num);
```

Value of `sign` is going to be `+1` or `-1` depending upon the type of input.

Comment: then OP has another float and still doesn't know if it is negative